# Set different top and bottom colspans to the same table row

Tags: html, css

I have a table with header that takes the whole width of it and has `colspan="5"`. But now I need to add one more row above the header, which can have more than 5 cells, for example 9, 16 or more. How can I make this new row to take only the width of old table but have many cells in it? You can see the problem below:

```css
.foo {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
}

.thClass {
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.foo tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.disp tbody tr th {
    column-span: all;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo disp elementTable">
  <tr colspan="1" class="newRow">
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableHeader">
    <th class="thClass" colspan="5">
      <span class="header">Device</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" id="sizeContainer">
      <ul id="displaySizes">
        <li>4:3</li>
        <li>16:9</li>
        <li>Clock</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/by29v71c/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you don't know how many table cells this new row will have and you want it to match the table below (and not the other way around) I placed the row into a new table nested inside the top most row, gave the top most row a colspan of 9999 (which means everything up to 9999) and that aligns it

```css
.foo {
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
}

.thClass {
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}

.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}

.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}

.foo tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.disp tbody tr th {
    column-span: all;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo disp elementTable">
  <tr colspan="1" class="newRow">
     <td colspan='9999999'>
       <table width='100%'>
          <tr>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>February</td>
            <td>February</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tableHeader">
    <th class="thClass" colspan="5">
      <span class="header">Device</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4" id="sizeContainer">
      <ul id="displaySizes">
        <li>4:3</li>
        <li>16:9</li>
        <li>Clock</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>February</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's a lesson learned from building email templates, where everything is a `<table>` - my pleasure